# Rails - param is missing or the value is empty: measure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a User model which has many measures, i got that error when submitting the new measure form, Any help, please ?

measure_controller.rb

```
def new
  @measure = current_user.measures.new
  respond_with(@measure)
end

def create
  @measure = current_user.measures.new(measure_params)
  @measure.save
  respond_with(@measure)
end

def set_measure
  @measure = current_user.measures.find(params[:id])
end

def measure_params
  params.require(:measure).permit(:math, :english, :history, :user_id)
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :users do
  resources :measures
end
```

measures/_form

```
<%= form_for([current_user, @measure]) do |f| %>


{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Ep8vKGiLTlLuHGRuisj6LWSNmHVIjKLmLVOE8hHjseI=",
 "math"=>"0",
 "english"=>"0",
 "history"=>"12",
 "commit"=>"Submit",
 "user_id"=>"1"}
```

Comment: Can you post the params log generated?

Comment: see the update, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `params` are not coming from `measure`, for a quick fix just change `measure_params` to below

```
def measure_params
  params.permit(:math, :english, :history, :user_id)
end
```